# How to print every ith to jth line from a text file?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to select a series of lines from a big text file. Every 50 lines is a unit. There are total 10,000 unit which means total 500,000 lines in the file. In each unit, I would like to extract the 2nd to the 8th lines.

For example, if I have the text file with total 12 lines. Every 3 lines is a unit.

a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
c 1
c 2
c 3
d 1
d 2
d 3

I would like to extract out the 1st to the 2nd lines in each unit. The result will look like:
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
d 1
d 2

Is there a quick unix command that can do the job?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%50 >=2 && NR%50 <=8' input-file
```